# How to test HSTS header, on IIS, Windows 2016 server?

Tags: https, hsts, http-redirect

I have Windows 2016 server with IIS, and everything set https. But security scanner reported:

```
HSTS Missing From HTTPS Server (RFC 6797)
The remote HTTPS server does not send the HTTP "Strict-Transport-Security" header.  Configure the remote web server to use HSTS.
```

If I look to the response in the browser Developer Tools, then I see only HTTPS with Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000. So I don't see it absent. How to test it? How to validate this security finding? Well, and how to fix it, if it's actually existing issue?

More details: In the IIS settings HTTP redirect is off.

[image: Request repsponse]

Answer (score 1):

If you system is accessible from the Internet, try https://observatory.mozilla.org/ or https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ They both look for the HSTS header.